# Redirect data:text/html with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, base64, redirect, data-url

I want to know how to redirect a data URL like this

```
data:text/html;base64,PGgxPiBIb2xsYSA8L2gxPg==
```

with `.htaccess` file.

I already did this it didn't work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ data:text/html;base64,PGgxPiBIb2xsYSA8L2gxPg== [L]
```